# VMware: make it direct first mouse click to VM

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

When I move the mouse pointer from another (host) program over the VM window and click on the guest GUI, the guest does not "see" the click. Only the VM is activated (the VM window gets focus). I must click another time to get the guest GUI to "see" my input.

Reference: this was (partly) discussed [on VMTM forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/170825), but with no solution.

My environment:

- host OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- VMWare Player 7.1.4 (v12.5.6 behaves the same)
- guest OS: Windows 7 64-bit (with VMWare Tools installed and running)

Comment: There was a bug where the initial mouse click was lost on Windows hosts.  I believe Player 7.x was affected; could you please try a newer version?  Player is free for non-commercial use, so there shouldn't be much reason to not upgrade.

Comment: @jamesdlin  v12.5.6 behaves the same.